# Why is Postgres throwing "ERROR: procedure returned null record"?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, inout

Below is a dummy query that returns no records:

```sql
WITH no_records AS (
  SELECT usesysid AS id, usename AS value
  FROM pg_user
  WHERE usename = 'non-existent-user'
)
SELECT
  jsonb_build_object(
    'id', id,
    'value', value
  )
FROM no_records;
```

Result:

```
 jsonb_build_object
--------------------
(0 rows)
```

But when I wrap the same query in a Postgres 13 procedure with an `INOUT` parameter

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_something(
  INOUT result JSONB DEFAULT NULL
)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
WITH null_record AS (
  SELECT usesysid AS id, usename AS value
  FROM pg_user
  WHERE usename = 'non-existent-user'
)
SELECT
  jsonb_build_object(
    'id', id,
    'value', value
  )
  FROM null_record;
$$;
```

... and I call it

```sql
CALL get_something();
```

... I get the following error:

> ERROR:  procedure returned null record

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9db3ff2dbee918698ff4187c0e1826a4)

Comment: Why not just use a function?

Comment: The reason I've gone with procedures is they provide a neat abstraction layer allowing me to define a very clear contract and also a simple permissions strategy: interaction with the database is only possible via procedures and I can revoke all `SELECT` permissions from my users, only letting them call specific procedures. Yes, I know I can `GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION` but it just makes things simpler to say: only `CALL` statements are permitted.

Comment: You still need `grant execute` for the procedure. That's the same as with functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with a as(
  SELECT usesysid AS id, usename AS value
  FROM pg_user
  WHERE usename = 'non-existent-user')
select row_to_json(a.*) from a;
```

It will return

```
 row_to_json
-------------
(0 rows)
```

There is nothing there, it's not null, null is value undefined. But null is something. here it's nothing.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_proc1(inout JSONB DEFAULT NULL)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
NULL;
END;
$$;
```

call it: `call test_proc1(null::jsonb);`
it will return:

```
 column1
---------
 [null]
(1 row)
```

Comment: your explanation makes sense and it has helped me resolve the issue. I've changed the language of the procedure to `plpgsql`, assigned the JSON object to the INOUT variable using the `SELECT .. INTO` construct and the error is gone. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=805e3866ed9417a6bc175514997e9863